# How to disassemble assembly code

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, disassembly

I used masm for compiling my assembly source code and I was curious, is there any way to convert that to back to source code.

 I  thought a way to use debugger to step through code, but the code is around 450 lines (contain loops, procedures).

Comment: so you are saying you have a compiled binary and you want to go back to the corresponding assembly? There is a class of programs called [disassemblers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler) that do exactly that.

Comment: depends on the format, some formats have clues to help the disassembler.  but in general for a variable length instruction set, you have to disassemble in execution order and some things are computed, so you cant always/accurately disassemble everything.  Dont expect to be able to.  there are some free and pay for disassemblers, gnu has a good one, but again even there, even with an elf file it is just taking a stab at it...

Comment: think of it this way if logic can interpret it then software can, so absolutely it is possible to parse through the program.

Comment: An assembler that can actually disassemble into MASM source code is [Agner Fog's `objconv`](http://agner.org/optimize/#objconv) (available for Windows, Linux, and OS X).  Don't count on being able to assemble back into a working binary, though, because a different encoding for an instruction (imm8 vs. imm32) might change the layout of the rest of the code in a way that breaks it.

Comment: I was able to decompile but now I used hexWorkshop,  as my friend gave me a puzzle and is hiding a answer inside it, It gave me whole memory dump but I am still not able to locate, where is it hidden

Answer (score 0):

## Disassembly on Windows

There isn't a built-in way to disassemble code, but the consensus for a third-party disassembler seems to be around IDA. It's typically not free, but for non-commercial 32-bit use you can download a [freeware version](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml).

## Disassembly on Linux

The GNU binutils package (which is typically included in your distro's development tools) contains a command called `objdump`, which quickly and easily disassembles Linux executables:

```
$ # -d means to disassemble code sections
$ objdump -d my_file
```

Comment: There are free disassemblers for Windows, including I think the Cygwin port of `objdump`.  (And BTW, `objdump -drwC -Mintel` will give you closer to MASM syntax, actually GAS's intel_syntax.)

Comment: An assembler that can actually disassemble into MASM source code is [Agner Fog's `objconv`](http://agner.org/optimize/#objconv) (available for Windows, Linux, and OS X)

Comment: Windows has much more than just IDA to offer: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/is-there-any-disassembler-to-rival-ida-pro

Comment: I've made this community wiki if anyone wants to list tools in the answer itself.

Comment: I used hexWorkshop, my friend gave me a puzzle and is hiding a answer inside it, It gave me whole memory dump but I am still not able to locate, where is it hidden